# How to connect to remote Jupyter server

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, jupyter

A company needs me to do some data analysis in Python for them. Unfortunately I am not familiar how I can log into the environment they prepared for me. They created an EC2 instance in which they have set up a Python environment for me. I have the URL, username and password and managed to log into this using putty on my windows 10 machine. What they also gave me is a URL to a "Jupyter server" (this is a https URL) and a password. My question is: how can I launch a jupyter notebook in this environment? I am really not familiar with this at all, so I first just tried "jupyter notebook" in the putty shell, which did not work. Then I entered the URL they gave me into my browser but then it tells me that the SSL certificate is invalid...
All I need is to create a jupyter notebook in a browser so that I can access their environment and the data they stored for me in this EC2 instance.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to connect to Jupyter Notebook on a remote server in order to run Python scripts remotely, you can use SSH tunneling. Run the following command on a client machine:

ssh -L 8080:localhost:8888 username@server_address

Comment: @FadySaad: it's better to link to the more detailed explanation when possible.  Particularly as he might not be aware that he needs to then point his browser and http://localhost:8080 if he's successfully followed your instructions (assuming that the remote Jupyter session is even on port 8888).

Comment: @Jim Dennis thanks, here is the link for more details: https://yangcha.github.io/Jupyter-Notebook/

Answer (score 0):

In general they may have this up in one of two or ways.  They might have followed these [Public Remote Access for Jupyter](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html) instructions ... with just a password or with password and SSL.

The more common method would be to use [Jupyter Notebook via ssh](https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh) ... because *ssh* can create a tunnel from any free port on your local system through it's (secure/encrypting) multiplexing connection where the packets are relayed by the remote *sshd* (deamon) to any given port on the remote's localhost (loopback) interface.

You should be able to use *sudo netstat -lnp* from your *ssh* shell session on the EC2 instance to see if the Jupyter process is listening on 127.0.0.1:8888 (or whatever port) or *:8888 (or whatever port).  In the former case (the default for Jupyter) you have to use *ssh* port forwarding.  In the latter, they should supply the password and you should connect with your browser to *http://....:8888* or to *https://....:8888* (with the appropriate IP address and TCP port numbers).  The IP address will be the same as you've been using to access the shell with *ssh*.

Answer (score 0):

They probably want you to access a Jupyter Notebook Server. ssl certificate errors are relatively common with them. I usually get around it by clicking

[image]
advanced -> proceed to https://ip-address:port/

If you are struggling with it, you can see this issue mitigated with the youtube below.

https://youtu.be/YBdYTgwb2OM?t=6m32s